# Regular expression to merge two lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to find a regular expression to merge the second and third lines.
There's no space after each line (only \r\n). I can look for lines that start with letters then merge them with the line above, but this would force me to match the first letter and lose it after replacing. Is there a way around that?

```
10921,Experimental Violation of a Cluster State Bell Inequality,2005,0,8570,?
10922,"Capital Budgeting and Compensation with Asymmetric
Information and Moral Hazard",2000,0,19530,?
```

Answer (score 0):

For merging 2nd and 3rd line you can try this with **matches newline** option

```
(^.*?[\r\n]+.*?)[\r\n]+(.*)$
```

Replace it with

```
\1\2
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could use /1 and /2 like that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Replace (^\d+.*)[\r\n]+(^\D+.*) with \1 \2
```

Answer (score 0):

By observing your inputs

Try this pattern:

```
(?>[^\?])([\n]+)
```

replace with `\s`

Answer (score 0):

You said: *I can look for lines that start with letters then merge them with the line above*

Then, try this is the pattern using multiline option:

```
([A-Za-z])[\r\n]+([A-Za-z])
```

Using Python, the option is re.MULTILINE. Using Java will be Pattern.MULTILINE.